# Create landscape image page in pdf, without breaking text flow

Tags: floats, pdf, landscape

Here is an MWE. If you compile this to PDF, you get a half-empty page on the first page, as the last part of the text doesn't come up, but is forced onto a new page. Compare this with the same thing, but with the `\begin{landscape}` removed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\chapter{blah}

blah blah

\section{something}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p!]
  \includegraphics{figures/someimage.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}


A whole lot more text.

\end{document}
```

Thing is, I really need a full page landscape for this particular figure, because it has so much detail. Is there a way to do this that doesn't break the text flow so badly? (perhaps using another package? the `pdflscape` documentation is horrendous - 14 pages, and only two lines dedicated to usage.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`landscape` does `\clearpage` you don't want that, just use a `figure` and rotate the image with

```
\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics...}
```

or if you want the caption on its side as well use the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the `rotating` package

Answer (score 13):

Package `afterpage` does the trick. If the environment `landscape` is put into `\afterpage` then the landscape page is inserted after the current page is completed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{blah}

blah blah

\section{something}
\afterpage{\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p!]
  \includegraphics{figures/someimage.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}}

A whole lot more text.

\end{document}
```