# Display PDF page with sidewaysfigure in landscape

Tags: floats, pdf, landscape

I want to have a landscape figure with the same portrait page geometry as the rest of the document. Additionally, I want *only* that page to be *displayed* in landscape in the PDF and the figure to float correctly.

This has very nearly been answered by:
[Answer 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71399/problems-with-newpage-and-pdfpageattr)
and
[Answer 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71482/create-landscape-image-page-in-pdf-without-breaking-text-flow).

I am currently using a sidewaysfigure environment. This works perfectly i.e., the resulting PDF document prints exactly as required; also the figure floats correctly. However, I would like the page which the figure is on to *display* in landscape when the PDF is viewed electronically.

I have tried using an afterpage environment as:

```
\afterpage{%
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{figure}
            FIGURE HERE
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
}% end afterpage
```

However, this breaks the floating of the figure.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: We'll need some code to work from: please edit in a full working example of what you have so far.