# Full sheet figures (no margins) without breaking the text flow

Tags: floats, fullpage

I want to make a kind of photobook with a simple layout: the left pages with a photo, which covers the entire sheet without any margin and without a caption or page number, the right pages always plain text. It works pretty bad using

```
\newcommand{\fullimg}[1]{
\newgeometry{left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm, bindingoffset=0mm}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{img/#1} %figures in subdirectory img
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry}
```

The problem is the text flow on the right pages - it is interrupted, as the figure must be positioned between two paragraphs. Thus it remains a lot of manual adjustment, and additionally, there are frequently some empty lines at the end of one page.

Comment: This may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, I found a solution using the packages afterpage and pdfpages:

\afterpage{includepdf{image.pdf}}

does the job. It has been already posted more than 7 years ago: [Create landscape image page in pdf, without breaking text flow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71482/create-landscape-image-page-in-pdf-without-breaking-text-flow/71494#71494)